# mysql common column criteria for joining tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

If I have two tables between which the join has to be performed, say

table 1:

```
groupdetails_table (groupid, no.of.members, created date)
```

table 2:

```
groupuserdetails_table (groupid, userid, role status)
```

Is that `groupid` must be a key column or it can be a normal column? I need an explanation for this.

Does it have to be a key column or not, and if so, why?

Comment: not related to your question, but do you really need to add the post fix `_table`  to all your tables? That make all table names unnecessary long

Comment: You may join your two tables using any columns you wish.

Answer (score 0):

`groupid` should be primary key for `groupdetails_table` and foreign key for `groupuserdetails_table`

in `groupuserdetails_table` you key probably should be a composite of `(groupid, userid)`

But you can join for any column you want independent of if they are key or not

Comment: thanks for ur reply,sorry am a beginner in mysql and need to know what is the main benefit i am going to get when i join based on key columns

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You join for the columns you need not the one give you a benefit. The benefit of creating a key is **db also create an index** allowing you do search on that column much faster also assure your table integrity. Well and when you join for a column with index ( or key) the join are also faster. But that mean you have to add index for those non key columns.

Comment: I also wish to know the poroces wht happens inside the sql engine when i give  (for eg.) as left join in my query,how the tables will joined (horizontally or vertically)?(background process in sql engine)

Comment: Again you are asking the wrong question. We cant give you a join tutorial here. You better check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp to learn more from examples

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the further architecture of your database. `groupid` looks like it should be the primary key on the table `groupdetails_table`... unless you have a different table called `group`. And `groupuserdetails_table` looks like an associative table between groupdetails and group.

In any case, if you want to perform a valid join in a relational database (like MySQL), the two columns should pretty much always be keys, be it foreign or primary. That is because making the columns keys ensures that fields with the same value are actually the same thing, and fields referring to different things can never have the same value.

If you were to have a table called `group` (or `groups`, depending on your preference), and did not assign the field `groupid` as a primary key, then two different groups could have the same id.

A foreign key ensures that a field in one table corresponds exactly with one field in another table. Say you have a table `group_user`, then its field `groupid` should be a foreign key, referring to group.groupid. It means that you cannot have any row in `group_user` refer to a non-existing group.

Thus, while you can technically join on any columns you want, in order to ensure the join makes sense the columns joined at should be keys.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have to be a key in terms of executability, since you can have a join condition not involving keys, but since it is an ID, you need to make it a `foreign key` to avoid future inconsistencies. If it is not a `foreign key`, then nothing prevents you from inserting/updating with values of `groupid` which do not exist in the reference `table`. Also, if it is not a f`oreign key`, upon removing a record from the reference `table`, you could end up having records hanging in the air, with a `groupid` value which no longer exists in the reference table.

Answer (score 0):

Smth is wrong with the DB Architecture here:

1. you should have unique id for each record in a table;
2. if you want to limit the max number of users then rename `no.of.members` into `max_members` (or like that), otherwise count the number of records in `group_user` records by `group_id`;

Also try to follow conditions of community

- use underscore symbol between words in a table or a column but not dot

I'd prefer:

```
group(id[key], created)
group_user(id[key], group_id, role, status)
and group.id = group_user=group_id
```